# How can I default initialize static class template variables

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, typename =  std::enable_if<std::is_default_constructible<T>::value>>
struct E {
    static T var;   
};

int main() {
    std::cout << E<std::string>::var << std::endl;
}
```

How can I have `E<T>::var` default constructed for each template instantiation of `E`? Currently I receiev linker error

```
/home/tE1MjB/ccEXSZtn.o: In function `main':
prog.cpp:(.text.startup+0x12): undefined reference to `E<std::string, std::enable_if<true, void> >::var'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
template<class T, typename T2> T E<T, T2>::var{};
```

after class definition.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/590994694f5d1a36)

Comment: Why the `{}` in initialization?

Comment: @shane: You may omit them in current situation (as variable is static), but I prefer [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) syntax over [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) syntax